# Add a new collation to a Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, collation, localization

I have these collations:

```
postgres=# select * from pg_collation;
  collname  | collnamespace | collowner | collencoding | collcollate | collctype  
------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------
 default    |            11 |        10 |           -1 |             | 
 C          |            11 |        10 |           -1 | C           | C
 POSIX      |            11 |        10 |           -1 | POSIX       | POSIX
 en_US      |            11 |        10 |            6 | en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf8
 en_US.utf8 |            11 |        10 |            6 | en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf8
 ucs_basic  |            11 |        10 |            6 | C           | C
(6 rows)
```

I installed a new locale on my system and I'd like to use it on postgres. It seems that the only way to install a new collate is using the `initdb` command, but it requires to make a `pg_dumpall`, delete the postgres data directory, run `initdb` and restore all the data from the dump. Isn't there an easier solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to create a new DB cluster. You can use [**`CREATE COLLATION`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createcollation.html) in Postgres 9.1 or later. Example in the manual:

> To create a collation from the operating system locale fr_FR.utf8
>   (assuming the current database encoding is UTF8):
>
> ```
> CREATE COLLATION french (LOCALE = 'fr_FR.utf8');
> ```

Be sure to read the chapter [Managing Collations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html#AEN35202) in the manual to understand the details. In particular:

> Within any particular database, only collations that use that
>   database's encoding are of interest. Other entries in `pg_collation` are  ignored.

I.e., the collation has to match your database encoding to be available.
But there's more. Read it.