# Equivalent of UTF8_UNICODE_CI collation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, collation, encoding, pattern-matching, case-sensitive

I would like a column in a table inside a PostgreSQL database (I am using version 9.6). I know of the `UTF8_UNICODE_CI` collation on MySQL, so I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE thing (
    id    BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
   ,name  VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL COLLATE "UTF8_UNICODE_CI"
);
```

but I get:

> ```
> ERROR: collation "UTF8_UNICODE_CI" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
> ```

Reading around, I found that the `pg_collation` table displays collations, which showed:

```
=# SELECT * from pg_collation;
 collname | collnamespace | collowner | collencoding | collcollate | collctype
----------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------
 default  |            11 |        10 |           -1 |             |
 C        |            11 |        10 |           -1 | C           | C
 POSIX    |            11 |        10 |           -1 | POSIX       | POSIX
(3 rows)
```

So it's clearly not there... Is there any way to add it, or obtain the behavior I want? (I want a search `WHERE name LIKE '%lala%'` to match `'lalá'`, `'LÂLÄ'`, etc.)

Comment: `create collation` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createcollation.html

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105147/add-a-new-collation-to-a-postgres-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Postgres, you would typically solve this differently.

For starters, just use **`ILIKE`** for case insensitive matching. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)

> The key word `ILIKE` can be used instead of `LIKE` to make the match
> case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the
> SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

```
WHERE name ILIKE '%lala%'
```

You do not need a different collation for this. Trigram indexes support both case sensitive and insensitive pattern matching:

- [LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337500/939860)
- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

Or use the more portable **`lower(col) LIKE`**

```
WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%lala%'  -- pattern must be lower case, too.
```

- [Generic Ruby solution for SQLite3 “LIKE” or PostgreSQL “ILIKE”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278943/939860)

Or you could use the special data type `citext` provided by the additional module [citext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html):

- [Index on column with data type citext not used](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105244/index-on-column-with-data-type-citext-not-used/105250#105250)

If you insist on a special collation, you can create your own:

- [Add a new collation to a Postgres database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105147/add-a-new-collation-to-a-postgres-database)

I would *not* do that.

If you want to take string "normalization" one step further (remove all diacritic signs), look to `unaccent()`:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

You can combine both, instructions in the linked answer. More here:

- [PostgreSQL accent + case insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28636000/939860)

Overview:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

---

I would just use `ILIKE` and support it with a trigram index for big tables. Preferably use the latest version Postgres 9.6. It has several improvements for trigram GIN indexes.