# Sort name by Thai character is not working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, collation

I am trying to sort a table by name. The name are in Thai character;

```
>Select name from product_categ
                    name                    
--------------------------------------------
 ระงับกลิ่นกาย
 สกินแคร์ (ดูแลผิวหน้า)
 รองเท้า
 ผู้หญิง
 เมคอัพ
 น้ำหอม
 วิตามิน อาหารเสริม
 เส้นบุก, บุกก้อน
```

When I try to sort the table by name, it does not work.(it does sort but is sorting in some different way / probably using the equivalent of Thai Character ?)

```
>Select name from product_categ order by name;
                    name                    
--------------------------------------------
 ชา กาแฟ เครื่องดื่มชงสำเร็จ
 ร่ม กันฝน พวงกุญแจ
 หมวก
 หมวก
 เล็บ
 แป้ง
```

So i tried to google and find a solution where i came across using collation directly in the query.However the query is not working for me.

```
select name from product_categ order by name COLLATE 'th_TH';
```

I receive and error mentioning error at 'th_th';

Any suggestion to fix this will be a much appreciated.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12

Comment: first try to install `th_TH.UTF-8` locale by using `dpkg-reconfigure locales` if you haven't. then you should restart postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that it's a UTF-8 collation:

```
SELECT name
FROM product_categ
ORDER BY name COLLATE "th_TH.UTF-8";
```

Comment: you can create a new collation. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105157/110455

Comment: Nice one, @McNets. This is my first time dealing with Thai collation anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new DB using the command below;

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb WITH
  TEMPLATE = template0
  ENCODING = 'UTF8'
  LC_COLLATE = 'th_TH.UTF-8'
  LC_CTYPE = 'th_TH.UTF-8';
```

After that I run this query in `testdb`;

```
SELECT
  word, upper(word)
FROM (
VALUES ('ชา กาแฟ เครื่องดื่มชงสำเร็จ'), ('ร่ม กันฝน พวงกุญแจ'), ('หมวก'), ('หมวก'), ('เล็บ'), ('แป้ง')) AS
  words(word)
ORDER BY 1;
```

And I got following result;

```
          word          |         upper
------------------------+------------------------
 ชา กาแฟ เครื่องดื่มชงสำเร็จ | ชา กาแฟ เครื่องดื่มชงสำเร็จ
 ร่ม กันฝน พวงกุญแจ        | ร่ม กันฝน พวงกุญแจ
 หมวก                   | หมวก
 หมวก                   | หมวก
 เล็บ                    | เล็บ
 แป้ง                    | แป้ง
(6 rows)
```

I don't know your alphabet but if its ok, I can edit this post with details.